# Nashorn in JDK8 b80?

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

Anyone got any pointers on how to start playing with Oracle's new JS engine, Nashorn?

I've installed JDK 8 b80 and still only Rhino:

```
@Test
public void list() {
   ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
   List<ScriptEngineFactory> factories = manager.getEngineFactories();
   for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : factories) {
       System.out.println(factory.getEngineName());
   }
}
```

Output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7537...
Mozilla Rhino
```

Comment: nashorn-jdk8 is a separate branch as of March 2013. You can check it out and build nashorn.jar separately. I updated my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13430909/993133)

Answer (score 1):

Install the JDK8 and create an alias for your JDK's jjs (Nashorn Interpreter), e.g., if you create a file called test.js, you can run the program with:

$ jjs test.js

Mac OS = alias jjs=’/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/jjs’

Windows = Define an environment variable called ‘JAVA8_HOME’ and point to your jdk8 folder, then you can invoke jjs by running this command:

> “%JAVA8_HOME%\jre\bin\jjs” test.js

Here's an example of a Nashorn App:
http://marcelorjava.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/code-walkthrough-online-kanban-board-with-nashorn/

Comment: On a Mac, you don't need to (and probably shouldn't) hardcode the path to jdk8. Use: `alias jjs='$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)/jre/bin/jjs'`

Comment: I like (cd /usr/bin/ ;  ln -s $JAVA_HOME/bin/jjs jjs) myself.  That way I can use jjs in shebang scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't like the alias-thing either, so as wickund suggested I'll put it short (and also use the trick hohonuuli posted)

```
cd /usr/bin; ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)/bin/jjs jjs
```

Do it as root, else you won't be lucky because of missing permissions