# Nashorn under Java 7

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I'm trying to get Oracle's Nashorn running under Java 7.

I've cloned the repo and compiled the source. All I had to do to get it to compile was:

- Change jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.* to org.objectweb.asm.*
- Change one line that had Long.hashCode() static.

Everything seems happy, and Java 7 sees Nashorn as a scripting engine; but when I try and get an instance:

```
NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine();
```

I get the exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.newGlobalTrusted(Context.java:831)
>     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.newGlobal(Context.java:636)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$2.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:270)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$2.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:266)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.createNashornGlobal(NashornScriptEngine.java:266)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.(NashornScriptEngine.java:104)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.(NashornScriptEngine.java:78)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(NashornScriptEngineFactory.java:139)

jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global is in my class path. Does Nashorn use a different class loader maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried getting it to work under 7 previously and was met by the same error as you have. I think it has to do with the fact that Nashorn makes use of some new features in Java 8.

There is a [backport](https://bitbucket.org/ramonza/nashorn-backport/) of Nashorn for JDK 7 on bitbucket; I wrote a blog post detailing how to use it on my works blog [here](http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/03/how-to-make-use-of-nashorn-on-java-7/). You can also look at [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427793/how-can-i-start-coding-with-oracles-nashorn-js-engine-and-when-will-it-replace/15635135) for more information.

That bitbucket project hasn't been updated in some time, I'd recommend that you use the preview of [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/) if you want to play with Nashorn.

Comment: Thanks. There are a lot of changes to the Nashorn source between the code that's available now and the bitbucket backport. The Nashorn code that's giving the errors above isn't even in the bitbucket version.

Comment: I stopped using it as soon as a Java 8 preview came out that contained Nashorn in it. If your using Nashorn via the JSR223 API your code will work with Rhino in Java 7 if written correctly which is how I develop with them both at the moment.