# Java 7 application errors because trying to use new Java 8 Javascript engine Nashorn

Tags: java, javascript, java-7, java-8, nashorn

My java application which is packaged with java 7 gave the following stack trace on a customers computer. It seems to be trying to use a Java 8 new Javascript engine even though it is definently running Java 7, any ideas ?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.newGlobal(Context.java:778)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$3.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:425)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$3.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:421)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.createNashornGlobal(NashornScriptEngine.java:421)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.<init>(NashornScriptEngine.java:181)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.<init>(NashornScriptEngine.java:152)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(NashornScriptEngineFactory.java:141)
at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(Unknown Source)
```

I dont know if he has Java 8 installed (butIve asked) but I do know he is actually using Java 7 to run the application because an automatic check and log I do at startup. which gives

18/02/2014 21.47.09:com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong:writeSystemInfo:INFO: SongKong 1.17.0  using Java 1.7.0_45 24.45-b08 32bit on Windows 7 6.1 x86 initialized successfully

The failing code is simply:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

Comment: Can you post the code that leads to this?

Comment: Code looks fine. Did you compile your code using Java8? That can be the problem - not sure though!

Comment: Yes, I may have done because I do have java 8 installed, but why would a> that be a problem. b> only seem to be a problem for this customer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a bit of a dig around ...

The `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager` relies on a SPI mechanism to find and register `ScriptEngineFactory` classes.  Essentially, it trawls the classpath, looking for these classes.  Apparently, in in your case, this has resulted in it finding `NashornScriptEngineFactory`.

But why?

Well there are only really 3 possibilities:

- You have a JAR file that includes Nashorn on your application's classpath.
- You are using a JVM that includes Nashorn in one of its JAR files.
- Someone has added the Nashorn in the Java installation's extensions directory.

To find out which, I suggest that you use `find` to find all of the JAR files on the client system, then use `jar tvf some.jar | grep Nashorn` to try to find which JAR is providing the Nashorn classes.

Comment: Sorry Ive now clarified that the application is being run using Java 7, Ive added log excerpt to confirm this. I'm not using java 8 simply because the prereleases have all done a funny things with installers not rendering gui button correctly, if this is fixed I would be happy to move to Java 8 but I don't understand why a Java 7 install is looking for Java 8 code.

Comment: They haven't come back to me (its a Windows 7 system actually). But I have tried out latest Java 8 and looks fine so will bundle Java 8 JRE and build with Java 8 JDK for next version hopefully that will solve his issue, thanks.

Comment: Answer is sitting next to this post on right hand side "Nashorn under Java 7" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929981/nashorn-under-java-7?rq=1.

Comment: @RaviH - No it isn't.  >>This<< question is about why Nashorn is being used on Java 7 at all.  The OP doesn't want it.  Or at least, that is my interpretation.  He just wants a working Javascript engine ...

Comment: @StephenC In one plane that question itself answers - naive attempt to run Nashorn engine in Java 7 fails with the same error. Apparently Paul Taylor's customer getting this error has done that kind of naive attempt to run Nashorn under Java 7 by just including nashorn jar in classpath. If at all that person really needs to run nashorn under java 7, that person has to try the Java 7 backport as suggested in the answer to that post.

Comment: @RaviH - You are continuing to make assumptions ... with insufficient evidence to support them.  And one of them is that neither Paul Taylor or I noticed that other Question.  I (for one) did notice it, and I thought / think that doesn't Answer this one.

Comment: @RaviH Stephen C is correct ,I'm not actively trying to run Nashorn with Java 7, the application just seems to be trying to use it. And I have nothing from the customer to indicate they are actively trying to run Nashorn either, although that is a possibility.